# Relational calculus: what is a range-restricted variable?

Tags: databases

I know that if the set of free variables for a relational calculus query is equal to the set of range-restricted variables then the query is (roughly) safe. I also can identify free variables. However, I do not understand what range-restricted variables are at all, and I can't find any comprehensible explanations anywhere. Can anyone give me a hand? This is for domain relational calculus.